# Single stanza followed by two stanza's of lyrics

Tags: lilypond

I'm looking for how to have a first set of lyrics with one stanza and following with more than one. Haven't been able to find an example. See how below the lyrics for first eight bars are unnecessarily repeated?

```
\version "2.18.2"

\header {
  title = "Minimart"
  subtitle = "Derived from Traditional Balkan Song: Rumelaj"
  poet = "Text by Mike iLL"
}

melody = \relative c'' {
  \clef treble
  \key g \minor
  \time 4/4
  \repeat volta 2 { c4. b8 c b c( a) | r8 bes4 a8 bes( a) g r8 |
  g a bes c d( c) bes c | g a4 a8 a4 a8 r8 | }

 \repeat volta 2 { d8 cis d c d c d( c) | d cis d c d( c) bes( a) |
  g bes b b b b c( b) | r a4 a8 bes( a) a8 r | }
}

text =  \lyricmode {
  There's a mi -- ni -- mart | on the cor -- ner |
  At the mi -- ni -- mart is a | moon -- pie, I'm rea -- dy. 

  \set stanza = #"1. "
  Need I need I need a high | Pen -- ny pen -- ny pen -- ny
  Need I need I need a high | God al --  migh -- ty.
}

second_stanza = \lyricmode { 
  There's a mi -- ni -- mart | on the cor -- ner |
  At the mi -- ni -- mart is a | moon -- pie, I'm rea -- dy. 
  \set stanza = #"2. " 
  Lift me lift me lift me high | Hea -- ven Hea -- ven Hea -- ven |
  Lift me lift me lift me high | God al -- migh -- ty.
}

harmonies = \chordmode {
  d1:7 | g1:m | g2:m/f g2:m/ees | d1:7
  d1:7 |      | g1:m  | d1:7   |
}

\score {
  <<
    \new ChordNames {
      \set chordChanges = ##t
      \harmonies
    }
    \new Voice = "one" { \melody }
    \new Lyrics \lyricsto "one" \text
    \new Lyrics \lyricsto "one" \second_stanza
  >>
  \layout { }
  \midi { }
}
```

If I remove the duplicate first half of the lyrics, the second half gets shifted to the beginning.

Comment: and if you have more questions concerning LilyPond, please feel free to join the LilyPond mailing list, which is usually the best and faster way to solve your problems: https://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/lilypond-user

Comment: @Jongware thanks for commenting. Being that there's a lilypond tag, wouldn't that say that lilypond-specific questions are on-topic? How would this approach relate to module-specific questions like for Less or Applescript?

Comment: I absolutely agree with Mike on this one, this is about LilyPond's syntax and thus is on topic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A solution to your problem is to use the following construction:

```
this is an example
<<
  {this will be in the top}
  \new Lyrics {and this in the bottom}
>>
only a single lyrics line once again from here on
```

In your particular case, this results in:

```
\version "2.18.2"

\header {
  title = "Minimart"
  subtitle = "Derived from Traditional Balkan Song: Rumelaj"
  poet = "Text by Mike iLL"
}

melody = \relative c'' {
  \clef treble
  \key g \minor
  \time 4/4
  \repeat volta 2 { c4. b8 c b c( a) | r8 bes4 a8 bes( a) g r8 |
  g a bes c d( c) bes c | g a4 a8 a4 a8 r8 | }

 \repeat volta 2 { d8 cis d c d c d( c) | d cis d c d( c) bes( a) |
  g bes b b b b c( b) | r a4 a8 bes( a) a8 r | }
}

text =  \lyricmode {
  There's a mi -- ni -- mart on the cor -- ner
  At the mi -- ni -- mart is a moon -- pie, I'm rea -- dy. 
  <<
    {
      \set stanza = #"1. "
      Need I need I need a high Pen -- ny pen -- ny pen -- ny
      Need I need I need a high God al --  migh -- ty.
    }
    \new Lyrics {
      \set associatedVoice = "melody"
      \set stanza = #"2. " 
      Lift me lift me lift me high Hea -- ven Hea -- ven Hea -- ven
      Lift me lift me lift me high God al -- migh -- ty.
    }
  >>
}

harmonies = \chordmode {
  d1:7 | g1:m | g2:m/f g2:m/ees | d1:7
  d1:7 |      | g1:m  | d1:7   |
}

\score {
  <<
    \new ChordNames {
      \set chordChanges = ##t
      \harmonies
    }
    \new Voice = "one" { \melody }
    \new Lyrics \lyricsto "one" \text
  >>
  \layout { }
  \midi { }
}
```